# Can I set German spell checking to ignore the case of nouns?

Tags: spell-checking

German nouns are normally spelt w/ a capital first letter, but can I make the spell checker stop caring about that?

Comment: `:h spellcapcheck` ?

Comment: @VanLaser, that is only for caps at the beginning of sentences, as far as I can see.

Comment: Did you try it? `set spellcapcheck=`

Comment: @VanLaser, yes, I already have it my .vimrc.

Comment: The option is local to buffer. Just try this in a new buffer: `:set spell spelllang=de spellcapcheck=` and start testing.

Comment: @VanLaser, tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "Wie viel kostet das Hündchen im Schaufenster?" reports no errors to me with `set spell spelllang=de`, with default `spellcapcheck` (`spellcapcheck` is not for this). In fact, I get an error if I make the nouns lowercase. Could it be an old Vim?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot make the spellchecker take care of it. In fact, treating German nouns as lowercase would be an error.

Comment: According to contemp. rules, yes, not, for instance, in Grimm's dictionary.

Comment: Besides it should be possible to use lowercase privately. And when using a german word in English, kleinschreibung is arguably the most sensible, even if one cares about cont. rules.

Comment: That contradicts the official german spelling rules, besides, even Grimms dictionary won't adhere to the official rules anymore, since it is too old. The rule is, to uppercase write German nounds. Period.